# Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Customer Count' not found

Tags: r, error-handling, random-forest

I am trying to do a Random Forest model on a dataset to predict a two classification variable. I have attached the code below and come back with this error. The variable Customer Count is in the dataset and this error is still getting thrown.

This is for my predictive model. I have tried to reorganize the dataset to get around Customer Count as the first variable. I have also tried to trim the dataset so it is not as large and that maybe that was an issue.

```
# Load the dataset and explore
library(readxl)
rawData <- read_excel("StrippedTransformerModelData.xlsx")
View(rawData)

head(rawData)

str(rawData)

summary(rawData)

# Split into Train and Validation sets
# Training Set : Validation Set = 70 : 30 (random)
set.seed(100)
train <- sample(nrow(rawData), 0.7*nrow(rawData), replace = FALSE)
TrainSet <- rawData[train,]
ValidSet <- rawData[-train,]
summary(TrainSet)
summary(ValidSet)

# Create a Random Forest model with default parameters
model1 <- randomForest(data = TrainSet, Failure ~ ., ntree = 500, mtry = 6, importance = TRUE)
model1

Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Customer Count' not found.
```

The variable Customer Count is in the dataset for sure and I don't know why it is saying it is not found.

Comment: Column names should not have spaces in them.

Comment: We can't see your data, so we don't have a way to know what's wrong with the column specification